# expss tab_sort_* Not behaving as expected when tab_row_labels() present

Tags: r, expss

expss script below. Run without tab_sort_asc() and then with it.[last few rows].
The tab_row_labels get sorted. How can this be prevented?

```
mtcars %>%
  #####################################
  tab_row_label("Additional labels1 - means of numeric variable") %>%
  tab_cols(total(), vs) %>% 
  tab_cells(mpg) %>% #Numeric
  tab_stat_mean()%>%
  tab_stat_valid_n() %>%
  #####################################
  tab_subgroup(gear>3) %>% 
  tab_row_label("") %>% 
  tab_row_label("Additional labels2 - filtered for gears > 3") %>%
  tab_cells(vs,am) %>% # Categorical
  tab_stat_cpct(total_row_position = "above",
                total_label = c(" N", " Row %", " Col %"),
                total_statistic = c("u_cases", "u_rpct")) %>%
  ####################################
#tab_pivot()

tab_pivot() %>% 
  tab_sort_asc()
```

Comment: I think I have solved this issue by adding a # as first character in the row label